# how to iterate through ip addresses stored in variable and place these IP address in file using sed or awk

Tags: linux, shell

I have already googled through alot but no success for this scenario.
Hoping for useful suggestions

Thanks in advance for help...

I have few IP addresses stored in a variable [say IP={10.10.10.10 20.20.20.20 30.30.30.30}]

My requirement is to iterate through IPs in this variable, search text [say address] and insert this IP address in next line where text is found in a file.

example:

let's file content is as below, i have to search text "address" and add IPs below it

...

address

...

After replacing IPs file should look like-

...

address

address 10.10.10.10

address 20.20.20.20

address 30.30.30.30

...

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you meant this:

```
    IP="10.10.10.10 20.20.20.20 30.30.30.30"
```

You could put/split them in an indexed array:

```
    set -A ip ${IP}
```

Then you could loop over the array like so:

```
    for ((i=0 ; i<=${#ip[*]}; i++))
      do
        sed s/${word[${i}]}/${ip[${i}]}/g ${fileIn} > ${fileOut}
     done
```

*Note how I have assumed you have a matching array called word[] (it's unclear from OP whither the test to replace was coming from.)

Comment: thanks for response .. text to replace is in a text file.

it's not clear why to use word[] array.

Comment: any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive about the structure of the input.file, but I'll guess this:

```
    addy10
    10.10.10.10
    addy20
    20.20.20.20
    addy30
    30.30.30.30




    while read buff
      do
        if [[ ${buff} == [0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]* ]]
          then
            echo "${address} ${buff}"
         elif [[ ${buff} == [a-Z]* ]]
           then
            address=${buff}
        fi
     done < input.file
```